# Need a syntax highlighter for inserting code into a web page

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I have tried Google but I can't find the websit /utility I'm looking for. A while ago I found a website which lets you paste in Javascript and then it will produce html/css which you can copy and paste into your webpage which then displays the Javascript with syntax highlighting and proper indentation. Does anyone know what website this is or know of a similar website? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [ToHTML.com](http://tohtml.com/jScript/). Another options is [Highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/).